# Task pane is not showing VSTO

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, vsto

My task pane is not showing. If I put an `Msgbox` after visible, when I load up Excel I see it but when Excel loads completely, it's gone. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because this is my first time creating an VSTO and I'm following the docs on Microsoft to do so but stuck. Help?

```
Dim myUserControl As TaskPaneView
Dim myCustomTaskPane As Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    myUserControl = New TaskPaneView()
    myCustomTaskPane = CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl, "My Task Pane")
    myCustomTaskPane.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anything in it that could be throwing an exception?

Comment: I don't think so, there's nothing doing anything except just showing the task pane.

Comment: Turn on Trust Center Logging (File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Message Bar > Enable Trust Center Logging), run it again, and check the log file in %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Office\TCDiag\XLTCD.LOG. Look for entries that have a decision of Block Content.